# Drawing on other time frame in Pine script

Tags: pine-script

I need to draw some lines on the top of daily candles and keep them in lower time frames. It seems to me that Security function doesn't come handy because its main duty is plotting or giving the output to other functions. Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: Are you after every high of everyday?

Comment: yeah and I need to keep my daily drawing lines on lower time frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below shows you the daily highs as per your request.

```
//@version=4
study("Daily - Highs", overlay = true)

ShowDailyHighs = input(true, title = "Show Daily High", group = "Show / Hide Highs", type = input.bool)
dtf = "D", title = "Time Frame", type = input.resolution
is_new_bar(t) => 
    change(time(t)) != 0


float DdHigh = 0.0
float DHigh = 0.0
DHigh := security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
DdHigh := is_new_bar(dtf) ? DHigh[0] : DdHigh[0]


if ShowDailyHighs and is_new_bar(dtf)
    line.new(time, DdHigh, time+1, DdHigh, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.blue, extend=extend.right)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I was trying to solve this issue for dynamic lines. Image if we need to draw a line on top of today's candle and yesterdays'. I appreciate if you help me with that.

Comment: Draw it manually on TV then update you question with a link so I can see what you are explaining

Comment: I posted. Thank you.